# A point with given distance inside of a triangle.

Tags: geometry

> Triangle ABC has vertices A(0, 0), B(0, 3) and C(5, 0).  A point P
>   inside the triangle is rt(10) units from point A and rt(13) units from point
>   B.  How many units is P from point C?  Express your answer in simplest
>   radical form.

I'm not sure whether or not there is a formula for this. I'm kind of stuck and I'm thinking of just doing trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Triangle ABC has vertices A(0, 0), B(0, 3) and C(5, 0). A point P
>   inside the triangle is rt(10) units from point A and rt(13) units from
>   point B. How many units is P from point C? Express your answer in
>   simplest radical form.

The distance formula is given as the square root of the squares of the distance between the two points.

Because A is 0,0 we can say that if the coordinates of the missing point are (a,b) then (a^2) + (b^2) = 13, and assuming that the numbers are both integers, we know that two perfect squares add up to 13.

The only two squares adding up to 13 are 9, and 4. so by square rooting both, the coordinates can be either (3,1) or (1,3).

(1,3) wouldn't be inside the triangle, but (3,1) would work.

And the distance from (3,1) to (0,3) is rt(10).

Then you can find the distance from (3,1) to (5,0) and you should end up with: $$rt(5)$$

Comment: Why do you assume that the coordinates of $P$ must have integer values?

Comment: If not, this problem would be a lot harder to solve especially by hand. Also, (maybe by luck) it satisfied all listed conditions

Comment: It was a good guess! It’s not that much harder to solve without the guess, though. It becomes a matter of computing the intersection of two circles.

Comment: Oh, so by making two circles with a radius of rt(13) and rt(10) you could solve for the intersection... Makes sense, but it seems to take a bit longer to solve.

Comment: Subtracting one equation from the other leaves $y=1$. Plug that back into the equation of the circle centered at the origin.